# Getting the toolbar for Intellij

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I cannot find my menu bar for Intellij on the mac.  I want to be able to find the window options so I can show the console etc.

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with Windows 7 x64 & IntelliJ 13.0.1, but with the main toolbar and not the main menu.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was editing (update for your version of IntelliJ):

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties
```

And changing this line:

```
apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
```

To false

After restarting IntelliJ the menu bar re-appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a developer preview version of OS X Mavericks ? There the menu bar is not shown because some kind incompatibility. If this is the case you can fix it. See [this thread in the IntelliJ forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/449062;jsessionid=21E79C7FEF03BDB681AFFCC7D45E9C9F?tstart=0) or directly to the [bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112511).